# How to prevent myvector[3:(L-2)] reading backwards when L<5?

Tags: r, vector, indexing, seq

I am processing records from a large dataset with varying lengths using `data.table[, somefunc(someseries), by=]`. The length L of each record `someseries` could be anything from 1 to 50. I want to handle the following efficiently without needlessly adding an `if` expression:

For each group, I want the simplest way to access its middle entries `someseries[3:(L-2)]`

**Problem:** beware that when L<5, the expression `someseries[3:(L-2)]` actually misbehaves by inferring backwards direction. This is due to the default "helpful" behavior of `[from:to]` which uses 
`seq(from..., to..., by = ((to - from)/(length.out - 1) ...)` i.e. infers backwards direction `by=-1`

In that case I just want somefunc to get passed an empty `vector()` not `someseries[4:2]`

But you can't explicitly do `seq(... by=1)` because that errors if `from > to`.

Here's a testcase:

```
set.seed(15)
ragged_arrays <- lapply(ceiling(runif(5,1,5)), function(n) (1:n) )
# indexing with unwanted auto-backwards
lapply(ragged_arrays, function(someseries) someseries[2 : (length(someseries)-2)] )
```

For the sake of our testcase, `somefunc` is a function which behaves gracefully when passed an empty vector, e.g. `median()`

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want to drop the first two and last two elements.

```
ragged_arrays <- lapply(1:7, seq_len)
lapply(ragged_arrays, function(x) x[seq_along(x) > 2 & rev(seq_along(x)) > 2])
```

Comment: Great. Slightly lateral thinking. I was wondering if some data.table variable like `.N` would allow us to shortcut. I should have given a data.table testcase.

Comment: Sadly I am no data.table expert.